# Using an lvalue reference as a non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I read that the following types are allowed as non-type template parameters:

- integral types
- enum
- ptr to objects/methods
- lvalue reference to objects/methods
- std::nullptr_t

I don't understand how a non constant pointer or a lvalue reference is acceptable? Shouldn't they be constant types so that they are identified at compile time?

Obviously I'm no smarter than the standard so can someone show me an example of an lvalue reference and maybe a pointer being used as non template parameter?

Comment: It's possible because the object will surely exist, and the compiler knows the address at which it will exist. Therefore, hardcoding a reference to it inside your program is hardly a stretch.

Comment: There's no such thing as "non-template parameter". You're thinking of "non-type template parameter". (EDIT: Lies, there's one such phrase in footnote 137 (n3337), but that's non-normative text).

Comment: Why do you think lvalue reference is not acceptable?

Comment: If it will surely exist, I'm sure you can provide a simple example, can't you?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f39b547b4359aa15

Comment: Thank you guys for the clarification please add the answers and I will accept :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example which has both a method pointer and an lvalue reference as non-type template parameters:

```
int delete_counter_1 = 0;
int delete_counter_2 = 0;

template<int& ctr>
void increment_counter() { ++ctr; }

template<void(*func)()>
class Deleter {
    public:
    ~Deleter() { func(); }
};

int main() {
    { /* Internal scope */
      Deleter<increment_counter<delete_counter_1>> a, b;
      Deleter<increment_counter<delete_counter_2>> c;
    }
    std::cout << "Counter1: " << delete_counter_1
              << "; Counter2: " << delete_counter_2
              << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

See it on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d7c409407f52d68).

The interesting thing about the `Deleter` class is that it has no actual data members; its destructor can be directly inlined without indirect function calls.

As mentioned by Dalibor Frivaldsky in a comment, the point is that the (instantiated) functions `delete_counter<int&>` and the counters themselves have fixed addresses known at compile-time, so *as pointers* their values are constant. In particular, this is only true for objects with static lifetime; automatic ("stack-allocated") objects wouldn't work, and neither would non-static class members, but static objects (as above) and static class members are just fine.

Comment: Based on part of OP's question: "I don't understand how a non constant pointer or a lvalue reference is acceptable? Shouldn't they be constant types so that they are identified at compile time?", I think it is also worth noting that non-type template parameter has nothing to do with the const-ness of the type but the knowledge of the objects address at compile-time. That's why references and pointers to struct or class members (but not member functions!) cannot be used as non-type template parameters. And that's why you can use "delete_counter_1" or 2 - they will always have the same address

Comment: @DaliborFrivaldsky: non-static class members. static class members are fine, afaik. g++-4.8 also insists that the two delete counters have external linkage, but clang is fine with internal linkage; I need to track down why g++-4.8 thinks external linkage is necessary.

Comment: true, an important detail - non-static class members

Comment: @DaliborFrivaldsky: Hopefully clarified.

Comment: A non-type template parameter could be "lvalue reference to *objects*", but all the examples I've readed so far only shows "lvalue reference to *integral types*", does anyone have an example of lvalue reference to an object wich isn't an integral type?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster: Do you just want to convince yourself that it would work, or are you looking for a practical and useful example?

Comment: @rici I already answered my own question googling around and testing it myself, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Standard explains quite clearly in `14.3.2 [temp.arg.nontype]` what can be used as an argument if a non-type template parameter is a pointer or reference:

> - a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of a complete object with static storage duration
>     and external or internal linkage or a function with external or internal linkage, including function
>     templates and function template-ids but excluding non-static class members, expressed (ignoring parentheses)
>     as & id-expression, where the id-expression is the name of an object or function, except that the
>     & may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array and shall be omitted if the corresponding
>     template-parameter is a reference; or
> - a constant expression that evaluates to a null pointer value (4.10); or
> - a constant expression that evaluates to a null member pointer value (4.11); or
> - a pointer to member expressed as described in 5.3.1; or
> - a constant expression of type std::nullptr_t