# Using constexpr function as template parameter

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to use the result of a constexpr function as a template parameter and cannot figure out how to get it to work. I have the following code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string_view>

class slice
{
    public:
        template <std::size_t size>
        constexpr slice(char const (&data)[size]) noexcept :
            _size(size),
            _data(data)
        {}

        constexpr const char *data() const
        {
            return _data;
        }

        constexpr std::size_t size() const
        {
            return _size;
        }
    private:
        const size_t    _size;
        const char      *_data;
};

template <std::size_t size>
class key
{
    public:
        constexpr key(std::size_t hash, const char *data) :
            _hash(hash),
            _data(data, data + size)
        {}
    private:
        std::size_t             _hash;
        std::array<char, size>  _data;
};

class partition
{
    public:
        partition(std::string_view name) :
            _hash(std::hash<std::string_view>{}(name))
        {}

        auto operator()(const slice &data)
        {
            return key<data.size()>(_hash, data.data());
        }
    private:
        const std::size_t   _hash;
};
```

Without even trying to use these classes, it refuses to compile. I get the following error:

> error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
>
> ```
>        return key<data.size()>(_hash, data.data());
> ```

I have tried to not make the parameter to the operator() a reference, but that only adds more warning messages. I cannot make the _data member a constexpr, because apparantly that is not allowed.

I would use this code something like follows:

```
partition partition1{ "partition 1" };
partition partition2{ "partition 2" };

auto key1 = partition1("key 1");
auto key2 = partition2("key 1");
```

It's meant for a storage system to be able to create different partitions (or buckets) easily.

Comment: What would be the purpose of having `operator()` `constexpr` if you cannot have the constructor of `partition` `constexpr`?

Comment: @Holt: I don't really understand your point. The idea is that the operator() can create a key instance - with the right template parameter - automatically. That the partition constructor is not constexpr is totally irrelevant.

Comment: In order to call `operator()` on an instance of `partition`, you need to create an instance of `partition` first. If you do not have a `constexpr` constructor, you will never be able to create a `constexpr partition`, so you will never be able to call `operator()` on a `constexpr`, so the `constexpr` qualifier is useless.

Comment: OK, I'll remove the constexpr qualifier from the operator(). This does not change the original question though: How can I make the operator() select the correct template parameter for constructing key.

Comment: See my answer. If you want more details, you need to example code where you actually call this operator.

Comment: I have added an example. Of course, I see the fact that I could just make the operator() templated and accept a character array. I need to keep it separate this way, the slice class has more parameter and is used elsewhere, which I need to re-use.

Answer (score 4):

Your code cannot compile because in:

```
constexpr auto operator()(const slice &data)
{
    return key<data.size()>(_hash, data.data());
}
```

...`data` is not guaranteed to be `constexpr`. You could use a template parameter:

```
template <const slice& data>
constexpr auto operator()()
{
    return key<data.size()>(_hash, data.data());
}
```

...but then, what would be the point of making this `constexpr` if you cannot instantiate a `constexpr` `partition` due to the non-`constexpr` constructor?

Comment: This doesn't work of course. Template parameters can not be class instances.

Comment: @MartijnOtto This works if `data` is `constexpr`, but of course it does not work with non-`constexpr` data. If `data` is not-constexpr, you cannot access `data.size()` at compile time, so you cannot use `data.size()` as a template parameter.

Comment: @ildjarn No, it is not. You can use lvalue-reference as template parameter. See e.g., [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124797/using-an-lvalue-reference-as-a-non-type-template-parameter?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Of course you cannot call it like `<"key 1">` and expect the compiler to create a `const slice&` from a `const char[]`, but that's another story.

Comment: Well my compiler (clang 3.8.0) is not accepting it: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('partition' and 'slice'), and yes, that is with const data of course.

Comment: @MartijnOtto Works pretty well [here](https://godbolt.org/g/y3UGqB) (the error is unrelated to this). `const` is not `constexpr`, you need a static `slice` for this to work. This will not work in your case of course but I could not guess it before you post actual usage.